# How can I send byte[] with StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, serialization, tcpclient

Here is my method for sending data:

```
    // this method serializes an object and is returned as a string (Base64 encoded)
    public void Send(Packet packetData)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(cli.GetStream());
            string s = SerializeObject(packetData);
            w.WriteLine(s + "\n");
            w.Flush();
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException) { ShutdownClient(-2); }
    }
```

- cli is TcpClient object
- Packet is a serializable object

Here's my receive method:

```
    private string GetMessage(StreamReader r)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = r.ReadLine();
            s = s.Replace(" ", "");

            // this string is returned and then deserialized
            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception e) { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message); return null; }
    }
```

When I use this, 50% of the time it works. If it doesn't work, it's because of this:
**"The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 6D-2E-44-72-61-77-69-6E-67-2E-43-6F-6C-6F-72-0F-00 ..."**

I have tried using Encoding.Default.GetString/GetBytes in replacement of Base64, but then I get this:
**"Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization."**
If I print out the length of this (Default encoded) string, it is 183. But if I print out the actual string, nothing is printed.

How else can I send a byte[] as a string over StreamWriter?

Comment: Use the `streamWriter.BaseStream.Write`-method

Comment: Have you tried using a specific encoding at both ends? such as UTF8 or ASCII?

Comment: Also why are you removing characters from the stream at your getter?

Comment: Additionaly, the `\n` is not required as the `WriteLine` already appends a `\n` to it

Comment: @thefiloe It works, thanks. But now I'm getting another error "Unable to read data from transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately" but I'm pretty sure that's my useless setup acting up. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Yes, I have tried that. And I was removing spaces because Base64 can't have spaces in them. I heard that TCP sometimes messes up how your data comes in. I didn't know that. As soon as I appended \n it started working a little better, so I got excited.

Comment: TCP shouldn't mess up your data as the stack provides support for resending dead packets. Normally I use the TCPclient and TCPserver classes to do transmission as they have all this stuff built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How else can I send a byte[] as a string

Not the way you do it now, the byte[] content will get corrupted when the string is normalized.   A string should only ever be used to store Unicode characters.  Not every Unicode codepoint is valid.

If using a string is paramount then you should use Convert.ToBase64String() at the transmitter, Convert.FromBase64String() at the receiving end.

Do keep in mind that TCP is entirely capable of transferring binary data.  You possibly fell into this hole because TCP implements a *stream*, it doesn't do anything to help you transmit *messages*.  The simple way to transfer a binary 'message' is to first write the Length of the byte[].  The receiver first read that length, then knows what it should pass to the Read() call to recover the byte[] back from the TCP stream.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. I do exactly that, but sometimes the amount of data read is 2 or 3 bytes less than it should be, why does this happen?

Comment: You cannot read "less" when you count every byte.  Ignoring the return value of Read() is a standard bug.

Comment: Sent 180 | Read 180 | Sent 1920 | Read 1917 *program fails here*

Comment: Clearly that's a bug in your code, you should have called Read() again because you didn't get enough bytes.  Sure doesn't sound like you are actually sending the length of the byte[] as I recommended.

Comment: I send a byte array with a size of 4. I convert the Length of the message array to bytes using BitConverter.GetBytes, store it in the size array and then send it. Then the message byte array straight after.